# Pentaho Report - user authorization with password failed in java web app

Tags: java, postgresql, pentaho

I've generated report with Pentaho Designer Studio. Using Maven dependencies my project has all libraries including pentaho engine and jdbc driver.
When I launch `*.prpt` file in Report Designer - all works fine, report is generated correctly. But when I'm trying to launch my web app - I become error that user authorization with my password is not working -> `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`...

Question is why? All data needed to connect to database is in `*.prpt` file. In Report Designer everything works fine, in web app not. Can be that file *.prpt because of security reasons don't contains my password?
How can I include password into this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
Of course I was connected to db from web app. Problem was that in Pentaho Report Design I had to give full path jndi name, not only "~JndiName~", so server could see it. That means - java:/comp/env/postgres. Using name postgres in apache configuration jndi naming works fine.
I found that tip after 2 work-days reading about...

Answer (score 0):

Test that you connect to your database from your web-application outside of Pentaho (for instance by writing a small JSP file that does nothing more than establishing a connection to your database).

If that fails, fix your database configuration. It might be that your web-server is not allowed to connect to the postgresql instance.

Pentaho Reporting uses standard JDBC connections and usernames and passwords are stored within the PRPT file, unless you use JNDI connections. For JNDI connections you dont need usernames and passwords as these details are provided by the application container.